# Python sendmail - adding header to MimeMultipart to avoid hiding all recipients

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code which sends an email that uses HTML for templating.
All of the recipients get the message, but all of them are BCC.

```
def sendMail(to, cc, bcc, template, bodyParams, subjectParams):
    global connection
    if not testCurrentConnection(connection):
        connect(currentConnectionName)
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    subject, fromEmail, body = templateController.readTemplate(template)
    header = 'To: ' + to + '\n' + 'Cc: ' + cc + 'From: ' + fromEmail + '\n' + 'Subject: ' + subject + '\n'
    msg.attach(MIMEText(header, 'text'))
    if subjectParams:
        msg['Subject'] = templateController.replaceTextWithParams(subject, subjectParams)
    else:
        msg['Subject'] = subject
    if bodyParams:
        msg['Body'] = templateController.replaceTextWithParams(body, bodyParams)
    else:
        msg['Body'] = body

    msg['From'] = fromEmail
    msg['To'] = to
    msg['Cc'] = cc
    # no need to specify bcc here

    msg.attach(MIMEText(msg['Body'], 'html'))
    connection.sendmail(msg['From'], [msg['To'], msg['Cc'], bcc], msg.as_string())
    del msg
```

I'm calling the function like this:

```
smtpController.sendMail("myMail@gmail.com", "ccMail@gmail.com", "", "email.html", None, None)
```

(The last two variables are actually a dict with key-value mapping used to populate the HTML, but the problem reproduces without them)

I read that I need to add header to my message to prevent it but for some reason, adding the header doesn't change anything (lines 7-8 in the above code).
What am I missing?

Comment: I've never used this module but it would help if you could show how you're calling this function from the main program.

Comment: @ParvBanks I've edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I don't know how it makes a difference, but I fixed it by moving `msg['To'] = to` and `msg['Cc'] = cc` up, before `Subject` and `Body`. I completely removed the header.

```
def sendMail(to, cc, bcc, template, bodyParams, subjectParams):
    global connection
    if not testCurrentConnection(connection):
        connect(currentConnectionName)
    subject, fromEmail, body = templateController.readTemplate(template)
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['From'] = fromEmail
    msg['To'] = to
    msg['Cc'] = cc
    if subjectParams:
        msg['Subject'] = templateController.replaceTextWithParams(subject, subjectParams)
    else:
        msg['Subject'] = subject
    if bodyParams:
        msg['Body'] = templateController.replaceTextWithParams(body, bodyParams)
    else:
        msg['Body'] = body

    msg.attach(MIMEText(msg['Body'], 'html'))
    connection.sendmail(msg['From'], to.split(',') + cc.split(',') + bcc.split(','), msg.as_string())
    del msg
```